# The upgrade needs more free space on disk '/'

Tags: partitioning, upgrade, gparted

I'd like to upgrade from 16.04 to 20.04 passing through the 18.04. However, when I try to update to 18.04 I get:

```
The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 5.754 M free space on disk '/'. 
Please free at least an additional 3.059 M of disk space on '/'.
```

Here is the output of `df -h`:

```
$ df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3,9G     0    3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           789M  9,4M    779M   2% /run
/dev/sda5        19G   15G    2,6G  86% /
tmpfs           3,9G   92M    3,8G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M     0    5,0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G     0    3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       55M   55M       0 100% /snap/core18/1668
/dev/loop0      161M  161M       0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop2       28M   28M       0 100% /snap/snapd/6953
/dev/loop5       25M   25M       0 100% /snap/snapd/6434
/dev/loop4       59M   59M       0 100% /snap/discord/108
/dev/loop3       55M   55M       0 100% /snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop8       45M   45M       0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1440
/dev/loop7       58M   58M       0 100% /snap/discord/109
/dev/loop6       49M   49M       0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1474
/dev/sda6       421G  351G     49G  88% /home
/dev/sda1       496M   66M    431M  14% /boot/efi
tmpfs           789M   64K    789M   1% /run/user/1000
```

What is the best way of action given that (I suppose) I will later need some more space to upgrade to 20.04?

Comment: Free space, do the upgrade. Then you will `sudo apt autoremove` before upgrading to 20.04. And free up more space if needed.

Comment: @B.duGaray How do I free space, and where?

Comment: start with /var/cache/apt/archives/ but all the other stuff is going to needed. how about you enlarge / ? do you have more than 1 partition?

Comment: By deleting usless things or moving them on external drives (~/Videos ~/Music ~/Downloads ~/Documents). What `df -h` say in your term ? Edit your question with the results (in codeblock) ; /// `du -h -s *` might help you, also (but useless for us, and can contain sensitive information)

Comment: I use filelight to analyze disk usage

Comment: @B.duGaray really? All I need is to remove some files from, e.g., `~/Documents`?

Comment: @Py-ser start with */var/cache/apt/archives/* like Rinzwind suggested.

Comment: @Rinzwind I removed hundreds of MB from `/var/cache/apt/archives/` but I still need ~2.613M (which is to say 2.6 Gb in the most confusing way). How do I enlarge `/`?

Comment: Ok then. You have to know there will NEVER be 100% garantee you won't loss data when resizing partition, so be sure to backup everything important (or [better](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DriveImaging)) ; then you can [resize partitions](https://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted) with Gparted on a LiveUSB. Since sda5 (your `/`) and sda6 (your `/home) are neighbors, you can easly resize them and give some free space of sda6 to sda5.

Comment: Would suggest looking into getting an external drive to place/move data, videos and stuff like that.   Your drive is getting quite full and will probably run into this problem in the future again.  Should try to keep OS drives/partitions around 80% or less full.

Comment: @B.duGaray I am reading about `dd` from the link you suggested. Should I only get an image of one drive? Isnt' there a way to make an image (or clone) "everything"? I am no expert on this, and I am not sure what is the best way of action.

Comment: If there is nothing else to do than partitioning I will open a new thread, but first I'd like to know if that is the only option left.