# '/' not large enough to allow upgrade

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, upgrade, hard-drive

Follow up of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242883/the-upgrade-needs-more-free-space-on-disk), I want to upgrade from 16.04 to 20.04 passing through the 18.04. However, my `/` has not enough space. Even when I tried to follow suggestions to make some room, ~2.5Gb are still necessary. Is it better to resize the partitions or should I pursue a different action? If the former: because the `/` (/sda5) is close to the `/home` partition, is it enough to get a backup/disk image of these 2 or I need a 1Tb external drive to get an image of the whole internal disk?

Comment: Your question rules out clean-install, and requires upgrade. Therefore you have two courses of action: Eliminate unneeded files, or re-partition. You evidently given up on the former, so stick a LiveUSB in and start mucking with your partitions. I think you are making a mistake, and that you have ruled out or given up on easy and less-risky alternatives. But it's YOUR system, not mine, so get to it.

Comment: @user535733 thank you. I did not give up, I just do not know how to proceed since all I have done is deleting some files in `/var` and I am not confident enough to know what other files can I delete.

Comment: Then a better question would be "These are the 25 largest files I have in /var. Which ones are safe to delete? I'm looking to free up X MB." Instead you are asking about re-partitioning.

Comment: So `/var` is the only option to look for files to delete? How do I list the N largest files in there?

Comment: Use the Search Box at the top of the page. Try "List Largest Files" and scroll down a few. Lots of great ideas there on how to easily list your biggest storage hogs. DO NOT LIST THEM HERE. You already asked a completely different question here.

Comment: @user535733 I actually left the question pretty open just because I didn't know what was the best course of action. Where am I supposed to post them then? Should I start another post? That would be already the third one on the same line with no actual answer.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask to help you understand why nobody has answered, why I advised you to open a new question, and why it's a bad idea to use Comments for conversation.

Comment: Install `ncdu` and that will list the largest to the smallest files / folders in each.  You can start from `/` to show you.

Comment: Backup your /home partition. It is easy enough to restore it after doing a clean install. If you can create more space on the disk, leave /home and select it for home when installing but do not modify or format it.